# How to set an exception for using n/a with int

Tags: java, list, comparator

I am fairly new to Java. 
I am trying to read from a text file and for an integer value, the input maybe n/a from file. Now, I have to pass it further to a list and which will be sorted. And this n/a element will be compared using comparator. So can you please help me a bit with this? Thanks a lot!

Update 1:
Wanted to add code. As you can see above. One of these tokens can be a value n/a which is passed further to a constructor and then added to the list named data. I wanted to know how that can be resolved.

```
while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String l = sc.next().trim();
        String[] tokens = l.split(":");

        String n = tokens[0];
        String img = tokens[1];
        try{
        Integer he = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
        Integer a  = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
        Integer ho = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);
        Integer k  = Integer.parseInt(tokens[5]);
        Integer t  = Integer.parseInt(tokens[6]);
        Integer w  = Integer.parseInt(tokens[7]);


        ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon(imagePath + File.separator + img);

        SpaceShip ss = new SpaceShip(n, im, he, a, ho, k, t, w);
        data.add(ss);
        }
```

Comment: Did you give it a try?

Comment: Yes, I tried with try & catch but I am not able to pass the data still and elements with n/a are rejected when read by the list in integer form.

Comment: How are you parsing the file? What type of list are you passing the input into? What transformations are being made? Let's see some code.

Comment: Then please *share what you tried*

Comment: I hae added the code. Please reply now

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to only create an instance of a "SpaceShip" and add it to your "data" list if the string you are parsing does not contain any "n/a" values, then you could try checking your tokens to see if it contains any "n/a" values before trying to create a spaceship.

```
if (Arrays.asList(tokens).contains("n/a")) {
  throw new Exception("Can't create SpaceShip with n/a values");
  // you could just continue here if you want to ignore lines with n/a
  // values but still create SpaceShips if you have valid values
  // continue;
}
```